# How can I integrate $(\tan x)^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus

People, I've been trying solve this problem but I always arrive in a complex equation, am I going at the right way ?

$$ \int (\tan x)^{1/2}\, dx $$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, in my country we use tgx

Comment: And thanks for review ;)

Comment: [The answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28tan%28x%29%29) is not pretty.

Comment: I know, I've been tryng for weeks and nothing, I always arrive in a expression with complex solutions and after this I cannot continuate

Comment: @KalebRoncattideSouza can you show all your steps ?

Comment: Of course, by now I'm using a cellphone, soon I'll go to PC, then I post it

Comment: I Already posted it, at the post below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $t^2=\tan{x}$ gives $2t \, dt = \sec^{2}{x} \, dx = (1+t^4) \, dx $, so the integral is
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{1+t^4} $$
Now, this can be split into partial fractions using
$$ 1+t^4 = (1+\sqrt{2}t + t^2)(1-\sqrt{2}+t^2) $$
(don't feel bad if you didn't spot that: for a long time in the eighteenth century it was thought that this polynomial did not have a quadratic factorisation).

Now you just have to determine the partial fractions, and then it splits into things that you can do using arctangent and logarithms.

---

Okay, now we've found out where the problem is. Partial fractions are determined by making the guess
$$ \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2)(1-\sqrt{2}t+t^2)} = \frac{At+B}{1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2} + \frac{Ct+D}{1-\sqrt{2}+t^2}. $$
How do we arrive at this guess? You can show that the degrees of the numerators all have to be less than the degrees of the denominators in a case like this, so I have chosen the most general of this form. Now, we shall determine the constants. Multiply through by the denominator of the left-hand side:
$$ 1 = (At+B)(1-\sqrt{2}t+t^2) + (Ct+D)(1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2) $$
Now, both sides are polynomials in $t$. Therefore they are equal if and only if all the coefficients are the same (if you want a proof, think about the derivatives at $t=0$, for example). Hence we can consider each coefficient separately and obtain a different equation for each one: it will become apparent that these equations are enough to fix the coefficients. So, equating coefficients:
$$ \begin{align*}
1&: \quad 1 = B+D \\
t&: \quad 0 = A -\sqrt{2}B + C+\sqrt{2}D \\
t^2&: \quad 0 = -\sqrt{2}A + B +\sqrt{2}C + D \\
t^3&: \quad 0 = A+C \\
\end{align*} $$
Solving these equations gives
$$ A= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} , \quad B = \frac{1}{2}, \quad C=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \quad D= \frac{1}{2}, $$
so the partial fractions are
$$ \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2)(1-\sqrt{2}t+t^2)} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}t}{1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2} + \frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}t}{1-\sqrt{2}+t^2} \right) $$

---

Lastly, to integrate a fraction of the form
$$ \frac{At+B}{t^2+2bt+c}, $$
notice that the derivative of the denominator is $2t+2b$, so
$$ \int \frac{At+B}{t^2+2bt+c} dt = \int \frac{A(t+b)+(B-Ab)}{t^2+2bt+c} dt \\
= \frac{A}{2}\int \frac{2t+2b}{t^2+2bt+c} \, dt + (B-Ab) \int \frac{dt}{t^2+2bt+c}.  $$
The first integrates to
$$ \frac{A}{2}\log{(t^2+2bt+c)}, $$
and the second can be brought into a form suitable for a tangent substitution:
$$ \int \frac{dt}{t^2+2bt+c} = \int \frac{dt}{(t+b)^2+(c-b^2)}, $$
and so has integral
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\arctan{\frac{t+b}{\sqrt{c-b^2}}}, $$
if $c>b^2$ (else, use a hyperbolic tangent substitution).

Putting all that together will give the result.

Comment: I arrived here heheh but after this, I'm having problems about which solutions I have to get

Comment: Before or after getting the partial fractions?

Comment: after this, i got $$ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{(1+\sqrt{2}t + t^2)(1-\sqrt{2}+t^2)} dt $$ then exists some A and B that the last expression can be written  : $$ \int \frac{A}{(1+\sqrt{2}t + t^2)} + \frac{B}{(1-\sqrt{2}+t^2)}  dt$$

Comment: So now split it into partial fractions of the form
$$ \frac{At+B}{1+\sqrt{2}t+t^2} + \frac{Ct+D}{1-\sqrt{2}t+t^2}, $$
then you just have to know how to integrate $\frac{At+B}{a+bt+ct^2}$, which requires only a logarithm and (after completing the square) an arctangent. (And no, you need linear terms in the numerators for the equations to be consistent.)

Comment: Yes, but, to find A, B, C and D, I need to know which solutions of this complex equations $ (1+\sqrt{2}t + t^2) $ and $ (1-\sqrt{2}+t^2) $ do i have to take, then from there I'm having problems

Comment: you don't need to solve $(1\pm\sqrt{2}t+t^2)$ to find A,B,C,D

Comment: So tell me how can I find it, because the only way a thought was getting the LCM between the two splits, then I was trying to find At+B when Ct+D is 0

Answer (score 3):

A nice and elegant $alternate$ approach would be two consider the integrals $I_1$ = $\sqrt{tanx} + \sqrt{cotx}$ and $I_2$ = $\sqrt{tanx} - \sqrt{cotx}$. Then the required integral is 1/2 ($I_1$ + $I_2$). I think at this stage it suffices to say that express these in terms of sin and cos and for $I_1$ put $sinx - cosx = t$. The answer not only comes in elegant form, but is also much simpler to arrive at.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** let $x=arctg(u)\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$

Therefore: $$\int (tan\:x)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=\int{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{1+u^2}}du$$